# http://schema.org/LocalBusiness hasMap для Yandex и Google

Tags: seo, поисковая-оптимизация, schema.org, microdata

Использую http://schema.org/LocalBusiness для микроразметки.
Организация зарегистрирована на Google и Yandex картах.

Можно ли указать hasMap дважды: соответственно со ссылками на Google и Yandex карту организации?

Валидаторы ошибки не выдают.

Answer (score 0):

Разумеется вы можете это делать. Нет ограничений на применение этого свойства ни в спецификации этого типа в Схеме, ни в [**рекомендациях Гугл**](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не нашел описание алгоритма обработки hasMap ни у Яндекса, ни у Google. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32775898/1807736) предполагают, что Google и без hasMap покажет карту, на основе адреса.

Comment: Спецификация этого свойства: url для карты http://schema.org/hasMap.